# Run multiple instances of a Perl script

Tags: shell, perl

I have a Perl script which does some text processing. Now I want to run multiple instances of that script.

I tried to use the
[`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) module
to achieve this, but that module is not available on my server and I can't install it.

Is there any way to do this using Perl or shell script in the Unix environment.

Comment: `script & script; wait`

Comment: @ikegami could you please describe this command

Comment: And you are mistaken. You *can* install Parallel::ForkManager. No special permissions are needed.

Comment: @ikegami i know but i can't install that.

Comment: You "can't" ... because of OS permissions or because of corporate policy?

Comment: @glennjackman Because of corporate policy

Answer (score 1):

In shell scripting you can do it so easily like below:-

```
your_perl_script.pl &
your_perl_script.pl &
your_perl_script.pl &
wait
```

Here total 3 instances of your Perl script will run parallel. If you want more just add more like above.

Answer (score 1):

Is using [`fork()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) possible? Then just do it the hard way and `fork()` in the program itself as you like. Or maybe write a wrapper in a pattern of `fork();`[`exec();`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) or [`system();`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) if you need any output.